# Is there an analog of the Thom-Pontryagin construction for manifolds besides spheres?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, intuition, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

According to p.122, Chapter II, of Bredon's *Topology and Geometry*:

> **16.1 Theorem** (Thom-Pontryagin) The above construction gives an isomorphism of $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ with the group of framed cobordism classes of framed $k$-manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$.

Here and in what follows $k$ is assumed to be $k\ge 1$.

**Question:** Are similar results known to hold for $\pi_{n+k}(M^n)$, where $M^n$ is an arbitrary (compact) smooth $n$-manifold?

I.e. to what (known) extent are higher homotopy groups $\pi_{n+k}(M^n)$ similar to cobordism classes of $k$-manifolds?

A reference will suffice for an answer; please don't forget to include the page number.

---

We have (I think) for any $n$-manifold $M^n$, not just $S^n$, that $H_{n+k}(M^n)=\{0\}$ for all $k \ge 1$. Also, any smooth manifold is homotopically equivalent to a CW complex, for which all homology theories satisfying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms coincide.

Citing the Pontryagin-Thom construction, I would explain the intuition for the homology groups $H_{n+k}(S^n)$ vanishing to be that homology "ignores all information about cobordisms" (because if two $(n+k)$-cycles $c_1,c_2$ are such that $c_1-c_2=\partial d$ for some $(n+k+1)$-cycle $d$, then $[c_1]=[c_2]\in H_{n+k}(S^n)$). Thus, since by the Pontryagin-Thom construction the *only* information provided by $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ is about cobordisms, the Hurewicz homomorphism sends all of it to $0$.

Can we cite a similar intuitive reason for the homology groups $H_{n+k}(M^n)$ vanishing for an arbitrary smooth $n$-manifold $M^n$?

Comment: It's literally the same. The bijection is just to framed cobordism inside $M$.

Comment: Also note that "cobordisms" and "framed cobordisms" are totally different beasts. It's not that you're cataloging what kind of cobordisms exist in the homotopy case. Rather you're cataloging framed manifolds kid framed bordism instead of "singular manifolds mod singular bordism" = homology.

Comment: (Typo in my first comment - the LHS of bijection is $[M, S^{n-k}]$, RHS framed k-manifolds in M mod framed bordism)

Comment: Yeah but $[M, S^{n-k}]$ is different from $\pi_{n+k}(M)$.

Comment: @MikeMillerI did not know/realize how important the distinction between framed cobordism and cobordism was, sorry about that. I have to agree with Pedro -- I saw the corresponding theorem for $[M, S^{n-k}]$ in Bredon, but my question is about $[S^{n-k},M]$.

Comment: Then no. There is no such thing (that I know of).